# LinearLayout items won't change gravity

Tags: android, layout, gravity

I have the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout 
    orientation="horizontal" 
    layout_width="match_parent" 
    layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView 
            layout_width="50dp" 
            layout_height="match_parent" 
            srcCompat="@drawable/eshop" 
            id="@+id/imageView" 
            contentDescription="@string/eshop_icon_description"/>

    <TextView 
            id="@+id/game_price" 
            text="@string/game_price" 
            layout_margin="5dp" 
            layout_width="wrap_content" 
            layout_height="wrap_content" 
            textColor="#2196F3"/>

    <TextView 
            id="@+id/game_discount" 
            text="@string/game_discount" 
            layout_marginTop="5dp" 
            layout_marginEnd="5dp" 
            layout_marginRight="5dp" 
            layout_width="wrap_content" 
            layout_height="wrap_content" 
            textColor="#E91E63"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

I want The price and discount to be on the right and logo on the left, but they won't change using gravity_layout, or gravity.

What I'm missing?

Comment: Why are you using `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` for this kind of task?

Comment: Better to use constraint layout

Answer (score 0):

Make you `LinearLayout` orientation `vertical` instead of `horizontal`

then use `android:layout_gravity="left"` or `android:layout_gravity="right"`

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i have understood your question properly... But you want the same look as the image you have posted? I have added what I think the logo is, the green ImageView working as replacer...

You need to change the ImageViews src.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_sendr"
    />

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_sendr"
        />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/game_price"
                android:text="game_price"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#2196F3"/>

        <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/game_discount"
                 android:text="discount"
                 android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                 android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                 android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:textColor="#E91E63"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use ConstraintLayout like below?

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_smiley" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/game_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="$1.767"
            android:textColor="#2196F3"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/game_discount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:text="25%"
            android:textColor="#E91E63" />
    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Using this will make the Price & Discount move to rightmost position in layout, and the logo will remain to the left.

Now, I did this very quickly so you'll have to do all the adjustments to weird padding and margin that you'll get, but this works as you want it to.

Comment: Why are you nesting the two TextViews ? It's always better to have the less possible nested views.

Comment: It'd matter if there's a lot of nesting. Small nesting doesn't matter much. I'd have to write constraints for both the TextViews differently if I didn't nest them. So I made my task easier. @HartWoom